# Winedt - Spelling correction

Tags: winedt

I use the WinEdt to make text in Latex. However, I write in Greek and under each word shows a red line, which mean that the word is incorrect. It is very annoying. How can I disable this setting?

Comment: Click on the word "Spell" in the status line on the bottom.

Comment: I did not see this!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Or install and activate "spell checker" for Greek language (if it exist).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disable spell checking for your greek files, simply click on "Spell" in the status bar of WinEdt to disable this feature.

But I think it is better to install a Greek dictionary and have the spell checking feature on.

To do that, download the [Greek dictionary](http://www.winedt.org/dict/gr.zip) and unzip it wherever you want.

Then download the [InstallDict](http://www.winedt.org/macros/winedt/InstallDict.edt) macro in the same folder where you have unzipped `gr.zip`, open it in WinEdt and launch it (<kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd>).

Answer the questions the macro asks for:

- Write Greek on "Insert language name"

  [image]
- Write gr.dic on "Insert dictionary name"

  [image]

and you're done.

Now your greek documents have correct spell checking.

Add every word you like to the WinEdt custom dictionary by right-clicking on mispelled words and selecting "Add".

[image]